# disable the registration form

Tags: 9

How can I remove the *Registration* tab in Drupal 9?

> [image: screenshot]

Previously, this was possible by changing the user settings.

Comment: Set registration to administrators only.

Comment: I agree—nothing has changed about this.

Comment: quote «Set registration to administrators only.» I don't have such a function, I didn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure this:

1. Log in as an administrator.
2. Browse to /admin/config/people/accounts.
3. In the "Registration and cancellation" section, find the "Who can register accounts?" option.
4. Set the option to "Administrators only".
5. Save the configuration.